# mapcat using map and concat

Tags: dictionary, clojure, concatenation, reduce

In order to better understand *mapcat* I took an example:

```
user>  (mapcat #(list % %) [1 2 3])
(1 1 2 2 3 3)
```

And tried to reproduce what the doc describes using, on purpose, *map* and *concat* :

```
user> (doc mapcat)
clojure.core/mapcat
([f & colls])
  Returns the result of applying concat to the result of applying map
  to f and colls.  Thus function f should return a collection.
```

By doing this:

```
user>  (concat (map #(list % %) [1 2 3]))
((1 1) (2 2) (3 3))
```

However as you can see it doesn't work.  I can however use reduce like this but don't know if it's correct:

```
user>  (reduce #(concat %1 %2) (map #(vec (list % %)) [1 2 3]))
(1 1 2 2 3 3)
```

The above works but I don't know if it's a correct way to recreate, using *map* and *concat*, what *mapcat* does.

Basically I'd like to understand of *mapcat* works under the hood.

What is going on and how can I access the source of *mapcat*? (I'm using Emacs + nrepl)

Comment: Using `apply` is probably better than `reduce` here because `reduce` will do a `concat` for every pair of arguments. Since `concat` is lazy, when the values actually get forced you could end up with a _really_ deep call stack, possibly resulting in a stack overflow. [Here's a simple example.](https://www.refheap.com/paste/6409)

Comment: Just a tip - in your implementation with `reduce`, there's no need to wrap `concat` in an anonymous function. This will also work: `(reduce concat (map ...))` and is preferable because it better handles the case of empty input.

Answer (score 6):

```
user=> (source mapcat)
(defn mapcat
  "Returns the result of applying concat to the result of applying map
  to f and colls.  Thus function f should return a collection."
  {:added "1.0"}
  [f & colls]
    (apply concat (apply map f colls)))
nil
user=>
```

The reason [`reduce`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/reduce) also works is because it is effectively:

```
(concat (concat '(1 1) '(2 2)) '(3 3))
```

[`apply`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/apply), as used in the source code, expands to:

```
(concat '(1 1) '(2 2) '(3 3))
```

In your initial attempt with [`concat`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/concat):

```
  user=> (map #(list % %) [1 2 3])
  ((1 1) (2 2) (3 3))
  user=> (concat (list '(1 1) '(2 2) '(3 3)))
  ((1 1) (2 2) (3 3))
  user=> (concat [1])
  (1)
```

You can see that if you call `concat` with a single argument, it returns that argument.

Comment: (apply concat (apply map f colls)) looks weird.  I can't get it to work.  *(apply concat(map f colls))* does work for me, but I don't understand the double use of *apply*.  For example *(apply concat(apply map #(list % %) [1 2]))* doesn't work!?

Comment: Apply wants a list of parameters so the correct fortm for your example with only 1 parameter would be (apply concat(apply map #(list % %) [[1 2]]))

Answer (score 2):

`concat` is a variadic function i.e it can take n parameters where each parameter is a sequence of value i.e the signature becomes `(defn concat [& lst]])`. Whereas in your example you are calling concat with a single argument assuming that concat take a seq of seq of values to be concatenated and thats why you get the result i.e the same list of list is returned back.

`(apply concat(apply map #(list % %) [1 2]))` wont work.

`(apply map #(list % %) [[1 2]])` or `(apply map #(list % %) [1 2] [])` will work.

This is because apply expects the last parameter to be a sequence of values and each item in that sequence of values will be passed as a parameter to the applied function. In your case of apply being failed the call will expand to `(map #(list % %) 1 2)` which is wrong and the error message also shows it that it cannot convert long to sequence as map need sequences as parameters.